# How to promote reviewing of Section "First Questions"

Tags: discussion, review

Since a few months, I'm trying to help as much as I can reviewing post on SO (under 500 at the time of writing). But each time I connect, I see more and more First Questions to review.

I think the process is quite good: peer validation, double check, every first question is "flagged" to be reviewed.  Well nothing to say about this great feature.

But the number of "First Questions" is constantly increasing. In a way, this is good. That means that SO is more and more popular and useful. But we can't help everyone, and we are not superheroes.
Reviewing a post correctly is quite long... or at least it requires attention.

**So, is reviewing not attractive enough? Is it a matter that we can't improve?**

There is already a silver badge (reviewer for 1000 posts over 200 actionned). 
Stack Overflow provides more and more automatic procedures to correct posts, but it seems that it's not enough.

**What can WE do to improve that?**

Why not create some range based badges, like 200 review = bronze, 1000 = silver and 5000 (or more) for gold?

Why not create special operations, 'bounty like', to promote it? This may have drawbacks like unuseful review...

Well, I'm sure there are potential improvements, but I'm not sure that there is a solution :/

Comment: It's not part of the new review system yet, so that'll hopefully make the workflow a lot nicer. It'll also make it much more visible.

Comment: What is not in the new review system ?

Comment: The First Questions (and First Answers, and Late Questions) are in the  "Old Review Lists" section and use a more awkward workflow than the newer layout used for Low Quality Posts for example.

Comment: Eheh, ok. It's just that I don't have enough reputation to use it :). I still had to work ^^

Comment: This question is too localised, as the new review system will not have a section for first answers, or first questions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Are you sure about that?  The developers have mentioned more than once that more review tasks / categories will be added once they work all the kinks out of the new system.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Still, this question is discussing about the old revision system. It is not much helpful, as there is a new revision system undergoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big pitfall with badges for reviewing, is that some users try to get the badge and then stop reviewing (or at least with less fanatism).

The new (beta) reviewing tools solve this in a way, to provide a daily list of reviewers. So its still a target to get (be on top of the list) but the target has to be made each day. And yes this bites quality (see all posts on suggested edits). But when the numbers growing, the quality declines (its our task to keep them acceptable).

An other alternative would be to install professional reviewers to maintain quality and quantity, but I think that is still a bridge to far. So for now lets hope enough users with heart for the community, take on reviewing.

Comment: I'm agree with, the badged would bring less quality in review. Peer review is a great principle. I'm not sure, like you, that pro reviewers would be a great idea.

Comment: So, I'll be waiting for the new system :); Thanks.